# how to convert yolov3 patch coordinates array to bounding box array (x1,y1, x2,y2)

Tags: python, yolo

how to convert yolov3 patch coordinates array to bounding box array ?
i have lots of yolo patches coordinates arrays which look like this: (0,a,b,c,d) where  0<(a,b,c,d)<1 and i have the images every such array refer to, so i can extract the the image size (h,w,3). 
how do i get the patch location bounding box array (x1,y1,x2,y2) where (x1,y1,top left point) and  (x2,y2, bottom right point)

```
yolo_list=(0,a,b,c,d)
image_size=(h,w,3)
bounding_box_list=(x1,y1,x2,y2)
```

Answer (score 2):

1. For points that are just normalized coordinates (values between 0 and 1):

You have to implement the inverse of 'normalisation'.

In your case, if a pixel belongs to (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) and you have only the height and width of the image, you can easily deduce the real values/positions within the image.

For example, if x1 = 0.10 and y1 = 0.15, and if H=W=512 (say), you know that 0.10 * 512 == 51.2, int(51.2) = 51, and y1 = 0.15 * 512 == 76,8, int(76.8) = 76.

Therefore, the top-left coordinates are (51,76). Do this for the rest of your points and you will get the desired results.

2. For YOLO coordinates (very good explanation taken from the [Albumentations documentation](https://albumentations.ai/docs/getting_started/bounding_boxes_augmentation/) ):

In yolo, a bounding box is represented by four values [x_center, y_center, width, height]. x_center and y_center are the normalized coordinates of the center of the bounding box. To make coordinates normalized, we take pixel values of x and y, which marks the center of the bounding box on the x- and y-axis. Then we divide the value of x by the width of the image and value of y by the height of the image. width and height represent the width and the height of the bounding box. They are normalized as well.

Coordinates of the example bounding box in this format are `[((420 + 98) / 2) / 640, ((462 + 345) / 2) / 480, 322 / 640, 117 / 480]` which are `[0.4046875, 0.840625, 0.503125, 0.24375]`.

[image]

Comment: hi thx, does yolo arrays oriented as bounding box array? i mean if my yolo_list=(0,a,b,c,d) and image_size=(h,w,3) than bounding_box_list=(x1=int(a*w),y1=int(b*h),x2=int(c*w),y2=int(d*h))?

Comment: the question how to convert yolo coordinates is not strait foreword and i do ask for answer to that question. normalization is last operation first i need to know how to extract  (x1,y1,x2,y2) that is the actual question

Answer (score 0):

```
x1 = int((a-c/2)*w)
y1 = int((b-d/2)*h)
x2 = int((a+c/2)*w)
y2 = int((b+d/2)*h)
```

where

```
yolo_list=(0,a,b,c,d)
image_size=(h,w,3)
bounding_box_list=(x1,y1,x2,y2)
```

Comment: sorry add mistake with sign so: x1 = int((a-c/2)*w)
y1 = int((b+d/2)*h)
x2 = int((a+c/2)*w)
y2 = int((b-d/2)*h)